# How to break the streams in Docker awslog driver?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I do have a EC2 instance and a docker container running on it. Currently this docker container uses awslog driver to push logs to CloudWatch. If I go to CloudWatch console, I see a very large log stream (with container id as name) which contains all logs of last 16 days (since I've created the container). It almost seems like if I have this container running for 1 year, this log stream will keep all logs of 1 year. I am not quite sure what is the maximum size limit of a CloudWatch log stream, but most likely it will have a limit, at least I believe.

[image]

So my question is;

1. How to chunk this huge logstream? Hopefully by current date, smth like `{{.ContainerId}}{{.CurrentDate}}`
2. What is the maximum size limit of a CloudWatch log stream?
3. Is it a good practice to append onto a single huge log stream?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Working-with-log-groups-and-streams.html#SettingLogRetention

Comment: @jordanm My desire is to keep all logs forever but just keeping them chunked out. What is best approach in this way?

Answer (score 2):

The following is the definition of Cloudwatch Log Stream as defined in the docs, [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CloudWatchLogsConcepts.html)

> Log streams
>
> A log stream is a sequence of log events that share the same source. More specifically, a log stream is generally intended to represent the sequence of events coming from the application instance or resource being monitored. For example, a log stream may be associated with an Apache access log on a specific host. When you no longer need a log stream, you can delete it using the aws logs delete-log-stream command.

Unfortunately what you want is not possible at the moment. Not sure what exactly is your use-case but you can filter the logs streams using time, so separating them is not really necessary. See `start-time` and `end-time` in [filter-log-events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/filter-log-events.html)

You might want to define the following awslog driver options to get a better stream name.

`awslogs-stream-prefix` see [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html#create_awslogs_logdriver_options)